# Unable to connect to localhost using ip or pc name via wifi

Tags: iis-7.5, wifi, localhost

So I created an app and published it to wwwroot via IIS 7.5 on my local pc at home. I can access it via IP/Host from the pc the app resides on, but I can't access it from my laptop or phone via wifi.

Is there something with my router config that I have to enable? I can access shared folders from my laptop just fine.

I obtained my IP by doing an ipconfig...its the standard 192.168.0.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st step , can you ping the hosting server from your laptop ?
The command is ping 192.168.0.x (replace x of course)

if it does not work try disable the firewall on your hosting machine

Comment: I ended up having to create a new inbound rule in windows 7 firewall that allows my ip range to connect. Thanks mate